# Unable to install VirtualBox guest additions on Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS with HWE - why?

Tags: apt, 18.04, virtualbox, xorg, guest-additions

Recently I have installed HWE on my Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS running inside VirtualBox. It was a clean installation without any PPAs and without third-party repositories. Some info is below:

> ```
> $ head -n2 /etc/apt/sources.list
> #deb cdrom:[Ubuntu-MATE 18.04 LTS _Bionic Beaver_ - Release amd64 (20180426)]/ bionic main multiverse restricted universe
>
> $ hwe-support-status
> Your Hardware Enablement Stack (HWE) is supported until April 2023.
>
> $ dpkg -l | grep hwe
> ii  linux-generic-hwe-18.04                 4.18.0.15.65                            amd64        Complete Generic Linux kernel and headers
> ii  linux-headers-generic-hwe-18.04         4.18.0.15.65                            amd64        Generic Linux kernel headers
> ii  linux-image-generic-hwe-18.04           4.18.0.15.65                            amd64        Generic Linux kernel image
> ii  xserver-xorg-core-hwe-18.04             2:1.20.1-3ubuntu2.1~18.04.1             amd64        Xorg X server - core server
> ii  xserver-xorg-hwe-18.04                  1:7.7+19ubuntu8~18.04.2                 amd64        X.Org X server
> ii  xserver-xorg-input-all-hwe-18.04        1:7.7+19ubuntu8~18.04.2                 amd64        X.Org X server -- input driver metapackage
> ii  xserver-xorg-input-libinput-hwe-18.04   0.28.1-1~18.04.1                        amd64        X.Org X server -- libinput input driver
> ii  xserver-xorg-legacy-hwe-18.04           2:1.20.1-3ubuntu2.1~18.04.1             amd64        setuid root Xorg server wrapper
> ii  xserver-xorg-video-all-hwe-18.04        1:7.7+19ubuntu8~18.04.2                 amd64        X.Org X server -- output driver metapackage
> ii  xserver-xorg-video-amdgpu-hwe-18.04     18.1.0-1~18.04.1                        amd64        X.Org X server -- AMDGPU display driver
> ii  xserver-xorg-video-ati-hwe-18.04        1:18.1.0-1~18.04.1                      amd64        X.Org X server -- AMD/ATI display driver wrapper
> ii  xserver-xorg-video-fbdev-hwe-18.04      1:0.5.0-1ubuntu1~18.04.1                amd64        X.Org X server -- fbdev display driver
> ii  xserver-xorg-video-intel-hwe-18.04      2:2.99.917+git20171229-1ubuntu1~18.04.1 amd64        X.Org X server -- Intel i8xx, i9xx display driver
> ii  xserver-xorg-video-nouveau-hwe-18.04    1:1.0.15-3~18.04.1                      amd64        X.Org X server -- Nouveau display driver
> ii  xserver-xorg-video-qxl-hwe-18.04        0.1.5-2build2~18.04.1                   amd64        X.Org X server -- QXL display driver
> ii  xserver-xorg-video-radeon-hwe-18.04     1:18.1.0-1~18.04.1                      amd64        X.Org X server -- AMD/ATI Radeon display driver
> ii  xserver-xorg-video-vesa-hwe-18.04       1:2.4.0-1~18.04.1                       amd64        X.Org X server -- VESA display driver
> ii  xserver-xorg-video-vmware-hwe-18.04     1:13.3.0-2build1~18.04.1                amd64        X.Org X server -- VMware display driver
>
> $ uname -r
> 4.18.0-15-generic
> ```

Before the HWE installation I have installed `virtualbox-guest-x11`, but now it is removed. Moreover I can't install it again:

> ```
> $ sudo apt install virtualbox-guest-x11
> Reading package lists... Done
> Building dependency tree       
> Reading state information... Done
> Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
> requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
> distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
> or been moved out of Incoming.
> The following information may help to resolve the situation:
>
> The following packages have unmet dependencies:
>  virtualbox-guest-x11 : Depends: xorg-video-abi-23
>                         Depends: xserver-xorg-core (>= 2:1.18.99.901)
> E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
> ```

and HWE-named one too:

> ```
> $ sudo apt install virtualbox-guest-x11-hwe 
> Reading package lists... Done
> Building dependency tree       
> Reading state information... Done
> Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
> requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
> distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
> or been moved out of Incoming.
> The following information may help to resolve the situation:
>
> The following packages have unmet dependencies:
>  virtualbox-guest-x11-hwe : Depends: xorg-video-abi-23
>                             Depends: xserver-xorg-core (>= 2:1.18.99.901)
> E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
> ```

What should I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update:** the bug was fixed on 2019-03-08 with version `virtualbox-guest-x11-hwe` *5.2.18-dfsg-3~ubuntu18.04.3*.

---

It was dependency issue, so I have reported two bugs:

1. [bug 1816383 - Unable to install virtualbox-guest-x11 on 18.04.2 LTS with HWE](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/virtualbox/+bug/1816383)
2. [bug 1816386 - Unable to install virtualbox-guest-x11-hwe on 18.04.2 LTS with HWE](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/virtualbox-hwe/+bug/1816386)

So the most straightforward solution will be install ordinary kernel and Xorg and then remove HWE packages

```
sudo apt-get install xserver-xorg linux-image-generic
sudo apt-get purge xserver-xorg-hwe-18.04 linux-image-generic-hwe-18.04 xserver-xorg-legacy-hwe-18.04 xserver-xorg-core-hwe-18.04 xserver-xorg-video-intel-hwe-18.04
sudo apt-get autoremove
```

and then reinstall `virtualbox-guest-x11` with

```
sudo apt-get install virtualbox-guest-x11
```

Comment: By doing this on Linux Mint 19.3 (MATE) I was able to install the `virtualbox-guest-x11` package, but then X11 never started after reboot - I was stuck at a blinking cursor after the text boot part finished.

Answer (score 0):

You could try launch

```
apt-get install --reinstall virtualbox-guest-x11-hwe
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but it does not work (show above error about *unmet dependencies*).

Comment: ok, You could try launch ap-get aptitude and aptitude reinstall virtualbox-guest-x11-hwe

Comment: Oh dear, it is dependency issue. We can not fix it this way. It will remove HWE.